# how to update model with sequelize using hooks life cycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, associations

I'm trying to update A model instance based on another instance data.
A Model called Stock and another one called  Order. The remaining stock is adjusted accordingly based on the quantity ordered by the user.

```
//1.) Stock Association with Order
      this.hasMany(Order, {
        foreignKey: 'StockFK',
        as: 'stocks',
      });

//and Order Model associated with the Stock
this.belongsTo(Stock, {
        foreignKey: 'StockFK',
        as: 'gasStock',
        allowNull: false,
      });
//This is my hook to update the stock remaining before saving the order to the database
Order.beforeSave(async (cusInst, options) => {
    const quantity = cusInst.quantity;
    const stock = await cusInst.getStock();

    if (quantity > +0) {
      stock.latestOrderedQuantity = quantity;

      console.log('QUANTITY', quantity);

      stock.remainingCounter = stock.countInStock;

      stock.remainingInStock =
        stock.remainingCounter - stock.latestOrderedQuantity;

      console.log('REMAINING IN STOCK', stock.remainingInStock);
      

      stock.remainingCounter = stock.remainingInStock;
      console.log('CURRENT CLM IN STOCK', stock.remainingCounter);
      
      await stock.save();
    }
  });
```

How can I update the remaining stock using hooks in the order model while creating an order?
Thanks....

Comment: I ave managed to figure out the problem as my Stock model had a beforeSave hook which was reverting the updated dat to its initital state hence I couldn't see the adjustments in real time as I hoped...